# Is it possible to influence the rate that a margin increases as I increase the viewport width using CSS?

Tags: html, css

Can I make a margin increase slowly or quickly?

For example, I’d like to be able to give the left ul in the footer nav bellow a margin of 3rem and then have its margin increase quickly to 10rem as I increase the viewport width by 200px.

However, I don’t want the big jump in margin that occurs if I were to use a media query, so that the nav will continue to look good at all the various viewport widths in-between.

[image]

```css
.footer-nav {
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  display: flex;
}
.footer-nav ul {
  margin-right: 3rem;
}

.footer-nav li {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.footer-nav a {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: "Fira Sans";
  color: #9fcfff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
   <nav class="footer-nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">View Courses</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">ML-in-Excel</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Terms of Use</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
```

Comment: I think `flex-gap` (now just `gap:`) is better than `margin` for this, btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `clamp()` <sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp())</sup>

```css
.footer-nav {
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  display: flex;
}

.footer-nav ul:first-child {
  margin-right: clamp(3rem, 10%,10rem);
}

.footer-nav li {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.footer-nav a {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: "Fira Sans";
  color: #9fcfff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="footer-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">View Courses</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ML-in-Excel</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Terms of Use</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this advice! I'm using clamp all the time now: here's a handy calculator that allowed me to achieve the desire behavior:                           
                                                                                                                      
https://css-tricks.com/linearly-scale-font-size-with-css-clamp-based-on-the-viewport/#for-those-who-dont-mind-that-edge-case

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `margin`, consider using `gap` instead (formerly known as `flex-gap`, and is shorthand for `column-gap` and `row-gap`). Also consider using `flex-wrap: wrap;` instead of having multiple `<ul>` elements.

```css
.footer-nav {
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
  .footer-nav ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    column-gap: calc( 3rem + 10vw );
    row-gap: 1rem;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;

    outline: 1px solid blue;
  }
    .footer-nav li {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;

      outline: 1px solid red;
    }
      .footer-nav a {
        font-size: 1em;
        font-family: "Fira Sans";
        color: #9fcfff;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
```

```html
<nav class="footer-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">View Courses</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ML-in-Excel</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Terms of Use</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice Dai! Your advice worked as well.